# Пустые данные при фильтрации

Tags: php, mysql

Передаю данные из формы в обработчик POST запросом, когда данные не фильтруются запись происходит нормально:

```
$pin = $_POST['pinx'];
$valuex = $_POST['valuex'];
$email = $_POST['emailx'];
$valuez = $_POST['valuez'];
$country = $_POST['countryx']
```

Когда же я начинаю фильтровать, в БД приходят пустые значения:

```
 $pin = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($_POST['pinx']))));
    $valuex = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($_POST['valuex']))));
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($_POST['emailx']))));
    $valuez = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($_POST['valuez']))));
    $country = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($_POST['countryx']))));
```

Все данные приходят либо в числах, либо в английской раскладке, кодировка базы, как и скрипта utf-8.

Comment: Какая версия PHP? И используйте mysqli::escape_string

Comment: 5.4, сейчас заменил на 5.2, проверю.

Comment: Соединение с MySQL установлено? Дело в том, что mysql_real_escape_string() работает только при установленном соединении с базой данных.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать вывод этих переменных после фильтрации, если пусто - пробуйте по одной функции что бы выявить какая обнуляет.